# Twitter Bootstrap. Active menu item marking

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, menuitem

I use standart twitter bootstrap menu:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li><a href="#">...</a></li>
<li><a href="#">...</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to mark active menu item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to add "active" in your li like :

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="#"></a> 
</li>
```

Comment: It's mark only one marked <li>, not current. It's static, not active.

Comment: Just add some javascript to make it active

Comment: You mean something from standart Bootstrap js tools?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can just add an id or whatever to identify each li and change their class to "active" when this page is loaded

Comment: document.getElementById("idOfCurrentli").setAttribute("class", "active");

Comment: And how to define idOfCurrentli :) ?

Comment: In your html : <li id="homePage"><a href="#">...</a></li> And then in the js of this page :

document.getElementById("homePage").setAttribute("class", "active");

Answer (score 1):

Add a class of the `active` to the `li`

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Comment: It's mark only one marked <li>, not current. It's static, not active.

Comment: then add a class to it anyway: `.marked { background: red; }` then put `<li class="marked"></li>` or in css declare: `.nav li:first-child { background: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
        var storedListItem = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedListItem');
        $("ul.nav > li > a:eq("+(storedListItem)+")").addClass("active");
        $("ul.nav > li").on("click",function(){
            var index = $(this).index('ul.nav > li');
            var selectedListItem = index;
            sessionStorage.setItem('selectedListItem', JSON.stringify(selectedListItem));
        });
```

Comment: please provide a description of what this code does and how it resolves the question

Comment: When you click a list item in the menu the index of that list item is stored, it is then saved in session storage. One the page refreshes it is retrieved then  the active class is added to that item index. Showing the page as active. It resolves the question because it adds the active class after the page is loaded thus actually showing it as active, the answers above would not do that.